# Change number in left column based on number of apostrophes in right column pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe like the following.

| Num | Words |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello |
| 2 | can't |
| 3 3 3 | i like this |
| 4 4 4 4 4 | i don't can't do this |

Basically, each number corresponds to a word right now.

I want to add the same number twice based on how many apostrophes are in the 'Words' column, like the following. If there are two apostrophes, we would add 4 of the same numbers to the Num column.

| Num | Words |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello |
| 2 2 2 | can't |
| 3 3 3 | i like this |
| 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 | i don't can't do this |

I tried to do the following:

```
if "'" in str(x["Word"]):
        x["Number"] = repeat(x["Number"])
```

This only detects if there is an apostrophe, not if there are multiple and adds numbers based on that.

Comment: You could use the `str(x["Word"]).count("'")` to get a count of each apostrophe

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.count`. NB. The following code is vectorial (i.e fast,).

```
df['Num']+(' '+df['Num'].str[0].astype(str))*df['Words'].str.count("'")*2
```

Output:

```
0                    1
1                2 2 2
2                3 3 3
3    4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

To assign to the original dataframe:

```
df['Num'] = df['Num']+(' '+df['Num'].str[0].astype(str))*df['Words'].str.count("'")*2
```

Output:

```
                 Num                  Words
0                  1                  hello
1              2 2 2                  can't
2              3 3 3            i like this
3  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4  i don't can't do this
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.str.count` to count the number of apostrophes first, and then multiply the 'Num' column by that amount.

```
# get the number of apostrophes of each word 
num_apostrophes = df['Words'].str.count("'")
# get the first word of the 'Num' column, 
# assuming that it be anything (and not just 1 digit numbers)
first_num = df['Num'].str.extract("^(\w+)", expand=False)
# update 'Num'
df['Num'] += (" " + first_num) * 2 * num_apostrophes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.count("'")`, and then add it that many times.

```py
for x in range(str(x['Word']).count("'")):
    x["Number"] = repeat(x["Number"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might work... A little bit "workarroundish" but seems to work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Num': ['1', '2', '3 3 3', '4 4 4 4 4'], 
              'Words': ["hello", "can't", "i like this", "i don't can't do this"]})

cont = df['Words'].str.count("'")
num = df['Num'].str.slice(0,1)
df['Num'] = df['Num']+(" "+num)*cont
df
```

|  | Num | Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | hello |
| 1 | 2 2 | can't |
| 2 | 3 3 3 | i like this |
| 3 | 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 | i don't can't do this |